# How are strings freed in ATS2?

Tags: ats

http://www.ats-lang.org/Documents.html includes "Introduction to Programming in ATS", which includes the assertion that `fileref_get_line_string` returns a `Strptr1` (a look in `filebas.dats` shows that it returns a `String` via `strptr2string`), and it includes this code:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
#include "share/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"

implement main0() = loop() where
  fun loop(): void = let
      val isnot = fileref_isnot_eof(stdin_ref)
    in
    if isnot then let
      val line = fileref_get_line_string(stdin_ref)
      val () = print_string(line)
      val () = strptr_free(line)
    in
      loop()
    end else ()
  end
end
```

Which throws a type error if the `strptr_free` line is included. If that line isn't included, the program blatantly leaks memory. Is there current documentation or are there *ATS2* examples that show how the fileref_* words are supposed to be used? What is the *ATS2* version of the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of fileref_get_line_string: one in prelude/filebas and
the other in libats/ML/filebas. For getting linear strings, you need
the former:

```
#include
"share/atspre_staload.hats"

implement
main0() = loop() where
  fun
  loop(): void = let
    val
    isnot =
    fileref_isnot_eof(stdin_ref)
  in
    if isnot then let
      val line =
      fileref_get_line_string(stdin_ref)
      val () =
      print_strptr(line)
      val () = free(line)
    in
      loop()
    end else ()
  end
end
```